# react & redux - the component is rendering repeatedly due to api call placed in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I want to make an api call at the time when my component loads. I have the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getProfileDetails } from "../store/actions/profileAction";

class ProfilePage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getProfileDetails(this.props.currentUser.user, "");

        console.log("COMPONENTDIDMOUNT");
    }

    render() {
        var { currentUser, getProfileDetails, profile } = this.props;
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1>Profile Page for {currentUser.user.username} !!</h1>

            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }

}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return ({
        currentUser: state.currentUser,
        profile: state.profile
    })
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getProfileDetails })(ProfilePage);
```

The getProfileDetails fucntion:

```
export function getProfileDetails(user, detail) {
    return dispatch => {
        return apiCall("get", `/api/users/profile/${user.id}/${detail}`)
            .then(profileDetail => {
                dispatch(setCurrentProfile(profileDetail, detail));
                dispatch(removeError());
            })
            .catch(err => {
                dispatch(addError(err.message));
            })
    }
}
```

Here the function "**getProfileDetails**" is making an api call and then dispatching a redux store action which is setting the profile details.

The issue is that each time the getProfileDetails gets called, the redux store is updated and the component gets re-rendered, which in turn fires componentDidMount and **it goes into endless loop**.

Please suggest how to structure this.

Comment: what's the parent component? rerender shouldn't trigger componentDidMount? Only componentDidUpdate?

Comment: In the parent component, only routes are defined and I am using history.push() to come to this page.
I believe it is not only re-rendering but also de-mounting and re-mounting the component. When I am debugging, it does not wait for the api response and even before that it calls mapSateToProps. 
PS- the getProfileDetails function is only dispatching action to update profile, the currentUser is being handled by a different api call.

Comment: I have added the getProfileDetails fucntion in the question description

Answer (score 1):

What is the state property that you want to catch if it changes? For example, if you only want to call a new fetch if the `currentUser` changes, you could do this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.currentUser !== this.props.currentUser)
    this.props.getProfileDetails(this.props.currentUser.user, "");
}
```

You would need to initialize your data differently in `componentDidMount`, something like get it from state. Then only re-fetch the details if the user changes.

Comment: Hi, I have added the getApiCall function in the question description. The issue is that on debugging, it is triggering the mapStateToProps function even before the api response is received.
My goal is to simply make an api call and get the profile details on the load of this page(component).

Comment: It sounds like what you need to do is dispatch an action on componentDidMount to update your state with the results of the API call

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `mapDispatchToProps` instead of `mapStateToProps`. The latter only updates the component with existing state.

It looks like the issue you mentioned is discussed in the react-redux docs - https://redux.js.org/faq/react-redux#react-rendering-too-often. That might help you debug.

Please provide the code from the `../store/actions/profileAction` file.